# Neo4j consolidate nodes in cypher single node relationship

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I’m desperately trying to understand how to consolidate nodes in Neo4J for a more streamlined relationship.
I have a dataset with four columns:  Person_1_ID, Person_1_Name, Person_2_ID, Person_2_Name

How do you consolidate  IDs when they exist in two columns so that you only show one node?

## For example:

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

If I do a simple match and merge like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///users.csv' AS row
MATCH (Person_1:Person_1 {Person_1_ID: row.Person_1_ID})
MATCH (Person_2:Person_2 {Person_2_ID: row.Person_2_ID })
MERGE (Person_2)-[pr:REFERRING]->(Person_1);
```

It produces this:

[image]

I'm trying to merge on names/IDs so that the relationships look like this:

[image]

Desperately trying to understand how you merge nodes properly here so that the relationships are consolidated.  Any guidance and code example is greatly appreciated!

Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

In your initial node import, don't use Person_1 and Person_2 node labels. Just stick with a single node label Person. The same goes for person id node property. If I were you, I would just delete existing graph and use the following Cypher to produce the desired results:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///users.csv' AS row
MERGE (Person_1:Person {id: row.Person_1_ID})
MERGE (Person_2:Person {id: row.Person_2_ID })
MERGE (Person_2)-[pr:REFERRING]->(Person_1);
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  I knew that it was something simple but just couldn't see it. However, if you produce a single node label, how do you differentiate by colors, between the Person_ID_1 or _2 users?

Comment: you don't because sometimes a person ID 1 is also a person ID 2, like Dave in your example